# Edição tema filho wordpress com Bootstrap

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-3, wordpress-theme

algumas perguntas. Eu estou estudando child theme porque me falaram que é o melhor jeito de alterar temas.

**Pergunta:**

Eu estou mexendo bastante com bootstrap e gostaria de alterar um tema que tem bootstrap, no caso eu não vou utilizar o style.css porque eu quero adicionar coisas do bootstrap na pagina. Como eu devo proceder?

**Proposta de solução:**

Copio e colo o index.php do tema pai e colo no tema filho e altero as partes que eu desejo alterar? Correto isso?

**Outra possível dúvida:**

Como funcionaria a parte administrativa? Eu preciso editar o banner, por exemplo. Talvez também um texto de uma das três colunas abaixo do banner. A solução mais simples seria utilizar um plugin? A dúvida é se vai funcionar perfeitamente com o Bootstrap ou terá conflitos? É uma boa prática?

**Motivo da pergunta:**

Estou procurando as melhores soluções e práticas mais atuais.

Comment: Resposta pra 1a pergunta: Sim!
Resposta pras outras perguntas: Use plugins. Pq se um dia vc decidir mudar de tema será mais fácil.